# How could we see the image of ourselves in concave mirrors?

Tags: optics, reflection

Let's consider a  case where observer AB (let's suppose 'you') are standing on the radius of curvature of a concave mirror . The point A is your eye (as shown in the figure) and with the help of the ray diagram we can see that the image A' of the eye is formed exactly below the point A and at the same distance from the principal axis.  And that also means that all the light rays reflected from the eye intersect each other at point A'. But how can we see the image of our eye in the concave mirror if no light rays (that are reflected from the eye) reaches the retina of our eye?

(Since our eyes can see an object only if the light reflected by the object reaches the eyes.)

[image]

Comment: by looking from point B. How would you see yourself if you stood off to the side of a flat mirror?

Comment: @AdrianHoward it will be virtual image of same size but this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to say that we can see the object only when the light reflected by object reach in our. Although,the truth is we see the object when the light emit from object reach in our eyes(it can be reflected light or non reflected).thus,in this diagram we see the image of our eyes only when, one of millions or rays emitted by eyes reflected by the mirror reach back to our eyes otherwise we see the image of other part of object which light reaches in eyes back through mirror